# How to resolve data conversation failed in ssis package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

```
[Flat File Source [96]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "description" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
```

I am trying import csv file data into SQL server.i am using datatype nvarchar(4000) in sql .But in Flatfilesource proprties and Oledb Properties using same unicode STRING DT-WSTR.Before getting error cannot convert unicode and non unicode .That is why now i am using through data conversion control mapping the columns.Even if both datatype have same still getting this error.pls reply any one as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the row or rows that raised the error?

Comment: i am not able to provide those details..but row contain csv format only

Comment: Even some boolean type true or false is there ..some time this field also getting  same erro

Comment: The error could mean unicode to non-unicode or it could mean data length.  you need to start at the flatfile connection manager and make sure that the value is large enough.  Then go through the Source Adnanced editor and make sure the "description" column is still same encoding and size or larger size.  Check Inputs, And Outputs.  Then do the same for every transformation and source the column progresses to... If you need to do an actual conversion then you need to do that in a derived column.  There are probably minimum 5-10 places you need to look

Comment: Seems like an issue with the data length, do as what Matt suggested. Perhaps you'll want to scale down the problem first by reading the csv file and making sure it's read correctly before you proceed with the conversion and stuff.

Comment: without using Data Conversion i am getting this error.

Comment: [OLE DB Destination [539]] Error: Columns "aa_path" and "stg_asset_folder_path" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

Comment: i am using in table nvarchar(4000) that it shows in ssis unicode string DT_WSTR .For FlatFileSOurce it shows String_STR.when i am using data  conversion i changed as unicode DT_WSTR  and data length as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this [Data Conversion Transformation](http://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssis-data-conversion/) article then you will get an Idea